# Saving class data containing pyqt objects

Tags: python, pyqt, saving-data

I'm building a PyQt app and I'm quite beginner with python. Let's say I store an obj item in a defined class:

```
class Item (self):
    def __init__(self, item_nbr, crop_pixmap, originepoint, designation):
        self.item_nbr = item_nbr            # integer
        self.crop_pixmap = crop_pixmap      # QPixmap
        self.origin_point = originpoint     # QPoint
        self.designation = designation      # str
```

Then I work through a GUI perform other operation and create a list of Items. How can I save this list so that I can open it later ? pickle does not work with QPixmap and I'd like to save a single.

Comment: You need to define `__setstate__` and `__getstate__` methods for QPixmap yourselfe. Read the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__).

Comment: I've made a general pickler for PyQt5 see answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [QSettings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html) to save all your application data. It will automatically convert data types like `QPixmap`, `QPoint`, `QColor`, etc. By default, the settings are saved in a [platform-independant way](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#platform-specific-notes), but you can also save to a custom location if you want.

Here is how you could read/write your `Item` class:

```
def settings(self):
    # use a custom location
    return QtCore.QSettings('app.conf', QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)

def readSettings(self):
    self.items = []
    settings = self.settings()
    for index in range(settings.beginReadArray('items')):
        settings.setArrayIndex(index)
        self.items.append(Item(
            settings.value('number', -1, int),
            settings.value('pixmap', None, QtGui.QPixmap),
            settings.value('point', None, QtCore.QPoint),
            settings.value('designation', '', str),
            ))

def writeSettings(self):
    settings = self.settings()
    settings.beginWriteArray('items')
    for index, item in enumerate(self.items):
        settings.setArrayIndex(index)
        settings.setValue('number', item.item_nbr)
        settings.setValue('pixmap', item.crop_pixmap)
        settings.setValue('point', item.origin_point)
        settings.setValue('designation', item.designation)
    settings.endArray()
```

The PyQt version of `QSettings.value()` allows you to specify both a default value and the expected type of the value.

Comment: perfect exactly what I was looking for I love your suggestion